# How to get value from asynchronous local storage function and pass it to modal ionic 2

Tags: angular, ionic2, local-storage

I am fetching value from local storage and pass it to modal. In code bellow `console.log(obj);` line in the code prints initial value of the `obj` which is `{selectedRadious: 500, DistanceUnit: 'Meters'}` as `this.storage.get()` is asynchronous function. How to handle it to get local storage value?

```
let obj =  {selectedRadious: 500, DistanceUnit: 'Meters'};

this.storage.get('lastSetValue').then((val) => {

  if(val.selectedRadious){
    this.selectedRadious = val.DistanceUnit;
  }

  if(val.DistanceUnit){
    this.DistanceUnit = val.DistanceUnit;
  }

  obj = {selectedRadious: this.selectedRadious, DistanceUnit: this.DistanceUnit};
})
.catch(err=>{
});

console.log(obj);
let myModal = this.modalCtrl.create(SettingModalPage, obj);

myModal.onDidDismiss(data => {
console.log('modal value: '+data.DistanceUnit)
this.DistanceUnit = data.DistanceUnit;
this.selectedRadious = data.selectedRadious;

let objValue = {selectedRadious: this.selectedRadious, DistanceUnit: this.DistanceUnit};

this.storage.set('lastSetValue', objValue);
});
 myModal.present();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I have answered it here : [Can't resolve all parameters for Storage: (?)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43199250/cant-resolve-all-parameters-for-storage/43205017#43205017)

You need to move the code where you are accessing the values from a resolved promise into the `.then()` of that promise. Since, it is async operation, by the time you use it, it might not be available.

E.g. this could work:

```
presentModal() {
    this.storage.get('distUnit').then((val) => {
        console.log('Your distUnit is', val);
        this.DistanceUnit = val;
        this.storage.get('SetRadious').then((val) => {
            console.log('Your SetRadious is', val);
            this.selectedRadious = val;

            this.modalCreator();
        })
        .catch(err=>{
            console.log('Your SetRadious dont exist: ' + JSON.stringify(err));
            this.selectedRadious = 500;
            this.modalCreator();
        });
    })
    .catch(err=>{
        console.log('Your distUnit dont exist: ' + JSON.stringify(err));
        this.DistanceUnit = 'Meters';

        this.storage.get('SetRadious').then((val) => {
            console.log('Your SetRadious is', val);
            this.selectedRadious = val;

            this.modalCreator();
        })
        .catch(err=>{
            console.log('Your SetRadious dont exist: ' + JSON.stringify(err));
            this.selectedRadious = 500;
            this.modalCreator();
        });
    });
}

modalCreator(){
    let obj = {selectedRadious: this.selectedRadious, DistanceUnit: this.DistanceUnit};
    let myModal = this.modalCtrl.create(SettingModalPage, obj);

    myModal.onDidDismiss(data => {
        console.log('modal value: '+data.DistanceUnit)
        this.DistanceUnit = data.DistanceUnit;
        this.selectedRadious = data.selectedRadious;

        this.storage.set('distUnit', this.DistanceUnit);
        this.storage.set('SetRadious', this.selectedRadious);
    });
    myModal.present();
}
```

If you read the code carefully, you will get to know that I have handled all the cases for getting both the parameters and if one of them fails. Check it out and let me know.