# Warning: Can't resolve all parameters for Storage in PATH/node_modules/@ionic/storage/es2015/storage.d.ts: (?)

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic3

**Warning:**

> Warning: Can't resolve all parameters for Storage in
>   /Users/zzm/Desktop/minan/node_modules/@ionic/storage/es2015/storage.d.ts:
>   (?). This will become an error in Angular v5.x

I followed [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43199250/cant-resolve-all-parameters-for-storage) answer and did already. But still, shows this warning for me when I build `IOS` or `Android`.

**Package.json**

```
{
    "name": "ionic-hello-world",
    "author": "He Yuyang",
    "homepage": "http://ionicframework.com/",
    "private": true,
    "scripts": {
        "clean": "ionic-app-scripts clean",
        "build": "ionic-app-scripts build",
        "ionic:build": "ionic-app-scripts build",
        "ionic:serve": "ionic-app-scripts serve"
    },
    "dependencies": {
        "@angular/common": "4.0.0",
        "@angular/compiler": "4.0.0",
        "@angular/compiler-cli": "4.0.0",
        "@angular/core": "4.0.0",
        "@angular/forms": "4.0.0",
        "@angular/http": "4.0.0",
        "@angular/platform-browser": "4.0.0",
        "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "4.0.0",
        "@angular/platform-server": "4.0.0",
        "@ionic-native/core": "4.1.0",
        "@ionic-native/facebook": "^4.1.0",
        "@ionic-native/in-app-browser": "^4.3.0",
        "@ionic-native/onesignal": "^4.2.1",
        "@ionic-native/photo-viewer": "^4.1.0",
        "@ionic-native/qqsdk": "^4.1.0",
        "@ionic-native/social-sharing": "^4.1.0",
        "@ionic/storage": "2.0.0",
        "com-sarriaroman-photoviewer": "^1.1.10",
        "cordova-android": "^6.2.3",
        "cordova-ios": "^4.4.0",
        "cordova-plugin-console": "^1.0.5",
        "cordova-plugin-device": "^1.1.4",
        "cordova-plugin-facebook4": "^1.9.1",
        "cordova-plugin-inappbrowser": "^1.7.1",
        "cordova-plugin-qqsdk": "^0.9.6",
        "cordova-plugin-splashscreen": "^4.0.3",
        "cordova-plugin-statusbar": "^2.2.1",
        "cordova-plugin-wechat": "^2.0.0",
        "cordova-plugin-whitelist": "^1.3.2",
        "cordova-plugin-x-socialsharing": "^5.2.0",
        "es6-promise-plugin": "^4.1.0",
        "ionic-angular": "3.6.0",
        "ionic-img-viewer": "^2.6.1",
        "ionic-native": "2.4.1",
        "ionic-plugin-keyboard": "^2.2.1",
        "ionicons": "3.0.0",
        "onesignal-cordova-plugin": "^2.2.0",
        "rxjs": "5.0.0-beta.12",
        "sw-toolbox": "3.4.0",
        "zone.js": "0.6.26"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "@ionic/app-scripts": "^2.1.3",
        "typescript": "2.3.4"
    },
    "cordovaPlugins": [
        "cordova-plugin-whitelist",
        "cordova-plugin-console",
        "cordova-plugin-statusbar",
        "cordova-plugin-device",
        "ionic-plugin-keyboard",
        "cordova-plugin-splashscreen"
    ],
    "cordovaPlatforms": [],
    "description": "SidemenuTabs: An Ionic project",
    "cordova": {
        "plugins": {
            "cordova-plugin-console": {},
            "cordova-plugin-device": {},
            "cordova-plugin-splashscreen": {},
            "cordova-plugin-statusbar": {},
            "ionic-plugin-keyboard": {},
            "cordova-plugin-qqsdk": {
                "QQ_APP_ID": "1106340746"
            },
            "cordova-plugin-x-socialsharing": {},
            "com-sarriaroman-photoviewer": {},
            "cordova-plugin-facebook4": {
                "APP_ID": "2027324614162511",
                "APP_NAME": "民安-马来西亚"
            },
            "cordova-plugin-whitelist": {},
            "onesignal-cordova-plugin": {},
            "cordova-plugin-wechat": {
                "WECHATAPPID": "wxec56aa94e0b75717"
            },
            "cordova-plugin-inappbrowser": {}
        },
        "platforms": [
            "android",
            "ios"
        ]
    }
}
```

UPDATE:
provider **user-data.ts**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http } from '@angular/http';
import { Events } from 'ionic-angular';
import { Storage } from '@ionic/storage';

import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

@Injectable()
export class UserDataProvider {
  HAS_LOGGED_IN = 'hasLoggedIn';

  constructor(public http: Http, public events: Events, public storage: Storage) {
    console.log('Hello UserDataProvider Provider');
  }

  login(user: any): void {
    this.storage.set(this.HAS_LOGGED_IN, true);
    this.setUser(user);
    this.events.publish('user:login');
  };

  signup(user: any): void {
    this.storage.set(this.HAS_LOGGED_IN, true);
    this.setUser(user);
    this.events.publish('user:signup');
  };

  logout(): void {
    this.storage.remove(this.HAS_LOGGED_IN);
    this.storage.remove('username');
    this.events.publish('user:logout');
  };

  setUser(user: any): void {
    this.storage.set('user', user);
  };

  getUser(): Promise<any> {
    return this.storage.get('user').then((value) => {
      return value;
    });
  };

  hasLoggedIn(): Promise<boolean> {
    return this.storage.get(this.HAS_LOGGED_IN).then((value) => {
      return value === true;
    });
  };
}
```

Ionic Info

> cli packages: (/usr/local/lib/node_modules)
>
> ```
> @ionic/cli-utils  : 1.19.0
> ionic (Ionic CLI) : 3.19.0
> ```
>
> global packages:
>
> ```
> cordova (Cordova CLI) : 7.0.1
> ```
>
> local packages:
>
> ```
> @ionic/app-scripts : 3.1.4
> Cordova Platforms  : android 6.3.0 ios 4.4.0
> Ionic Framework    : ionic-angular 3.9.2
> ```
>
> System:
>
> ```
> ios-deploy : 1.9.2
> Node       : v6.11.3
> npm        : 3.10.10
> OS         : macOS Sierra
> Xcode      : Xcode 9.1 Build version 9B55
> ```
>
> Environment Variables:
>
> ```
> ANDROID_HOME : not set
> ```
>
> Misc:
>
> ```
> backend : pro
> ```

Comment: Can you show `Ionic info` and `package.json`?

Comment: @Sampath Sure..I will update my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I highly recommend upgrading your project to `latest Ionic` and Ionic `app-scripts`.

Ionic [**3.9.2**](https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic/releases)

See this [**official package.json**](https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic-conference-app/blob/master/package.json) file.

**Note:** After that delete the `node_modules` folder and run `npm i`

Comment: I will try to upgrading the project to 3.7.1, but I am worried about is it will show other error for me? Because now the warning not affect the project running.

Comment: You don't have any other option here.Because you need to upgrade your project anyway to get the latest features and bug fixes.I think this is the time for you. If you'll have different issues then you need to sort out those one by one.

Comment: Actually, I import { Storage } from '@ionic/storage'; in my provider, is it problem? And I update code in my question, please chack. Thank you!

Comment: You can do that.It is not the problem. Again latest `Storage` module is `2.0.1`.You don't have any other option.You must upgrade the app. https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic-storage/releases

Comment: You must upgrade the **whole project** according to the reference I have given. You know that Ionic is open source project and they fix huge set of bugs each and every version.So you must keep your project update always.

Comment: I upgraded my project to ionic 3.7.1 already, but still showing this error

Comment: Now it is `3.9.2` with `Angular 5` :D https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic/releases

Comment: I will update my ionic info in my question, please check...I tried 3.9.4 and angulea 5 already

Comment: Error solved..thank you very much..I delete node_modules and rebuild then success